# Can't decode data from a yml file

Tags: haskell, yaml, config

I want to read some basic settings from a yml file. Here's my attempt:

```
  #config.yml 
  some_value: "fdsfdsfd"


  #.hs
  yamlData <- BS.readFile "./config.yml"
  let var1 = Data.Yaml.decode yamlData :: Maybe String
  print $ "the key is " ++ fromJust var1
```

It returns `Maybe.fromJust: Nothing`. Should I necessarily create a `data` from `some_value` and implement `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` for it even if, like in my case, it's only one `String` field? Or is the issue somewhere else in my code?

Comment: Presumably you already have implemented `FromJSON`, `ToJSON`, else you would have gotten a compile time error.  Getting `Nothing` implies the yaml isn't in the format expected.  Why don't you try to produce yaml from a known Haskell item, to see what it expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I necessarily create a data from `some_value` and implement `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` for it even if, like in my case, it's only one `String` field?

Yes.

That said, there is a generic thing (a `Value`) to decode simple `yaml` data into if you don't want to set up your own `FromJSON` instance:

```
Prelude Data.Yaml> Data.Yaml.decode "some_value: \"fdsfdsfd\"" :: Maybe Value
Just (Object fromList [("some_value",String "fdsfdsfd")])
```

And furthermore since if we only want uniformly typed key value pairs, we can just decode into a `HashMap` and we get the following:

```
> Data.HashMap.Strict.lookup ("some_value" :: Text) =<< Data.Yaml.decode "some_value: \"fdsfdsfd\"" :: (Maybe String)
Just "fdsfdsfd"
```